# Detecting Rectangular Shapes in edge image with OpenCV

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing, hough-transform

I want to detect multiple (similar) rectangular objects in an image that have a lot of substructure within them. So, my current plan is to use gaussian blur, morphology and edge detection (`Canny`). After using edge detection I get this (with very low threshold parameters): [image]

What I want in the end is the outline of the greater rectangles. See: [image]

Currently I try to get this by using `HoughLines` and `findContours` afterwards. For this to work, I need to fiddle a lot with the threshold parameters for `Canny` and `HoughLines`.

When I get it right for one image the parameters most likely will not work for the next one (e.g. the edges in the previous image were less dominant leading to too many lines detected by the hough transformation). Another problem is that sometimes inner structures are equally or less dominant than one side of the outer edges.

I tried to use a stronger blur or morphology but at some point this blurred away the small gap between the rectangles.

Can I extract the bigger rectangles somehow else given the edge image (preferably with opencv)?
Getting the 4 corner points would be enough.

Comment: Can you post original image? You should try to detect contour with https://github.com/LaurentBerger/FilterChoice

Comment: You can try using DOG - Difference of Gaussian

Comment: Is the size of those rectangles fixed (or relatively stable at least)?

Comment: And do you know about `approxPolyDP` and the `matchShapes` functions? p.s. post your code, because without it people can only guess so far, about what is or is not missing in there.